The svg image using <use href=""> no longer works in chrome?
Since 20 June 2024, our both websites have stopped displaying svg sprite images in Chrome browser. The pictures have been displayed like this on the site for 4 years, we haven't had any updates to the site recently. However, everything still works in Firefox, Opera, and mobile Chrome.
Example of code on website bigtrip.by - All tours page:
<svg><use xlink:href="/img/public/icons.svg#fb"></use></svg>

Example of svg file "icons.svg":
<svg viewBox="0 0 25 25" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    symbol  { display: none }
    symbol :target { display: inline }
  </style>

  <symbol id="lock" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
    <path d="M400 224h-24v-72C376 68.2 307.8 0 224 0S72 68.2 72 152v72H48c-26.5 0-48 21.5-48 48v192c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V272c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zm-104 0H152v-72c0-39.7 32.3-72 72-72s72 32.3 72 72v72z"/>
  </symbol>

  <symbol id="fb" viewBox="0 0 25 25">
    <path d="M13.625 9.84375V7.71875C13.625 7.13225 14.129 6.65625 14.75 6.65625H15.875V4H13.625C11.7609 4 10.25 5.42694 10.25 7.1875V9.84375H8V12.5H10.25V21H13.625V12.5H15.875L17 9.84375H13.625Z"/>
  </symbol>

</svg>

Example on website
The "xlink:href" attribute is already deprecated, we tried replacing it with "href" - didn't help.
[Edited] The current version of Chrome is 126.0.6478.115. Updating Chrome to version 127.0.6533.17 (beta) did not help. There is a bug https://issues.chromium.org/issues/342579971 that was fixed, but not in current available betta version. So we will wait this fix about a month. Is there any work around?
I wouldn't close this thread as a duplicated. It can be the same problem and there is an answer in the above thread, but answer do not work actually. And the mentioned post is not resolved. The current post describes the problem in more detail.
[Resolved] Thank you for comments @ccprog and @herrstrietzel. Removing the inline styles from the svg file helped.
Another problem was that when you update the SVG that is used on the html page via , Chrome doesn't detect the change. Full page reloading, clearing cache, etc doesn't help. You can only see the updated version of the svg on the page by opening it in a new incognito window.

Please try using  instead of  in /img/public/icons.svg

You should check whether this has been reported to Chrome's bugtracker and report it yourself if it hasn't.

Is this already Chrome v126? I can't see the error in v125. Also, what is the inline style in icon.svg for? For spec-compliant browsers the first rule is enforced anyway, and the second rule can never be met (unless it is meant to be symbol:target, without the whitespace inbetween, which would then be overridden by the user agent).

Tested in current chrome: You should strip the unnecessary <style>  rules that don't make much sense as commented by  @ccprog. In fact you're mixing up the fragment identifier concept for <img> elements or CSS background related properties with the <use> element related  referencing. Both are controlled by Ids (like "#fb")  but <symbol> elements have by default a display:none property/rendering behavior. Apparently, the current chromium/blink core struggles with this. See plnkr example
